# XSLT Transformation requires counts

Tags: xslt, count

Hello I am transforming a csv file using XSLT files to pull training records out by employees.
What I know need to do is also pull a footer on the bottom of the CSV file with the total record count and somehow count each record that is transformed so I can do a compare of these in the system I am importing these into.

This is what the source file looks like -

TrainingRecord,,SP Training,,geoff.culbertson,,Trained,,IT
TrainingRecord,,SP Training,,jim.schultz,,Trained,,IT
RecordCount|2

So I need to transform the Record Count at the end of the file and do a count for each record in this example it would be 2 and transform that so I can do a compare.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?

Comment: I have the transformation of the file done with out the count part as this was added as a late requirements.

Comment: Show some code. What does your XML document look like? What is the XSLT you're using? What is the CSV output supposed to be?

Comment: The input is CSV - TrainingRecord,,SP Training,,geoff.culbertson,,Trained,,IT TrainingRecord,,SP Training,,jim.shultz,,Trained,,IT RecordCount|2

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <InboundMetadata>  
   
   <xsl:for-each select="//Line">
   <xsl:if test="./Element[1][text()='TrainingRecord']">
    <__service __serviceType="TcvTrainingRecordMaint">
     <xpath>//Line[<xsl:number value="position()" format="1"/>]</xpath>
     <ExitOnError>No</ExitOnError>
    </__service>
    </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>  </InboundMetadata>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I think the transformation XSLT is to big to post on here

Comment: Why are you using XSLT? I'd suggest awk or perl.

Comment: Please, *edit* the question and provide a complete but small sample source XML document. Without seeing it, very little can be said about the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very strange to use XSLT with a CSV as the input, but to answer your question, but based on the XSLT you've provided us, I believe you could obtain the row count with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//Line)" />
```